# Save scipy object to file

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I want to save the object `interpolator`generated from `scipy.interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline` to a file, in order to load it afterwards and use it.
This is the result on the console:

```
>>> interpolator
 <scipy.interpolate.fitpack2.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline object at 0x11C27170>
np.save("interpolator",np.array(interpolator))
>>> f = np.load("interpolator.npy")
>>> f
array(<scipy.interpolate.fitpack2.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline object at 0x11C08FB0>, dtype=object)
```

These are the results trying to use the loaded interpolator `f` with a generic value:

```
>>>f(10)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

or:

```
>>> f[0](10)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

How can I save/load it properly?

Comment: It's in a 0d array.  Try `f[()]` or `f.item()`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `interpolator` object is not an array, so `np.save` has wrapped it in an `object` array. And it falls back on `pickle` to save elements that aren't arrays.  So you get back a 0d array with one object.

To illustrate with a simple dictionary object:

```
In [280]: np.save('test.npy',{'one':1})
In [281]: x=np.load('test.npy')
In [282]: x
Out[282]: array({'one': 1}, dtype=object)
In [283]: x[0]
...
IndexError: 0-d arrays can't be indexed
In [284]: x[()]
Out[284]: {'one': 1}
In [285]: x.item()
Out[285]: {'one': 1}
In [288]: x.item()['one']
Out[288]: 1
```

So either `item` or `[()]` will retrieve this object from the array.  You should then be able to use it as you would before the `save`.

Using your own `pickle` calls is fine.

Comment: Hi @hpaulj, your answer is much better based on the OP's question. I've not really seen 0D arrays, in terms of `numpy.load`, wouldn't returning a one dimensional array with a single element be more intuitive?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like `numpy.save` and then `numpy.load` converts the scipy `InterpolatedUnivariateSpline` object to a numpy object. Numpy save/load [apparently](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.save.html#numpy.save) has an `allow_pickle=True` input to which should preserve object information. This isn't present in my version of numpy (1.9.2) and I assume maybe your version too. With `spl=numpy.load("file")`, the type information is lost and so the call `spl` as a method fails. As numpy save is mainly designed for binary arrays of data, the most general solution is probably to use `pickle`. As a minimum example,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import InterpolatedUnivariateSpline
import numpy as np
try:
    import cPickle as pickle
except ImportError:
    import pickle

x = np.linspace(-3, 3, 50)
y = np.exp(-x**2) + 0.1 * np.random.randn(50)
spl = InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(x, y)
plt.plot(x, y, 'ro', ms=5)


xs = np.linspace(-3, 3, 1000)

#Plot before save
plt.plot(xs, spl(xs), 'g', lw=3, alpha=0.7)

#Save, load and plot again (NOTE CAUSES ERROR)
#np.save("interpolator",spl)
#spl_loaded = np.load("interpolator.npy")
#plt.plot(xs, spl_loaded(xs), 'k--', lw=3, alpha=0.7)

#Pickle, unpickle and then plot again
with open('interpolator.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(spl, f)
with open('interpolator.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    spl_loaded = pickle.load(f)
plt.plot(xs, spl_loaded(xs), 'k--', lw=3, alpha=0.7)

plt.show()
```

Comment: `np.save` uses pickle for things it can't save directly.  In the OP case it first wrapped it in an object array.