# Python Load npz file included Scipy Object

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I can not figure out how to load scipy object properly. I looked the similar question '[Save scipy object to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34811957/)', but the dict example does not work for my situation.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.5
import numpy as np
x1=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
y1=np.array([10,20,30,40,50,60,70])

# Interpolate
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
interpFunc = interp1d(x1, y1, kind='cubic')
print('The intermediadate value is',interpFunc(2.5))

import os as osCommand
# Save
fileSaveDir = osCommand.getcwd() + "/test.npz"
np.savez_compressed(fileSaveDir,x1=x1,y1=y1,interpFunc=interpFunc)

# Let''s Load
data=np.load(fileSaveDir,'r',allow_pickle=True)
print(data['interpFunc'])
recallFunc=data['interpFunc']
print(recallFunc.item()[2.5])
```

The intermediate value is 25. It gives the following error:

```
The intermediadate value is 25.0
<scipy.interpolate.interpolate.interp1d object at 0x7ff3df5a8048>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "general.py", line 21, in <module>
    print(recallFunc.item()[2.5])
TypeError: 'interp1d' object is not subscriptable
```

If I should pickle module, can someone show me?

Comment: Before save you use `interpFunc(2.5)`.  Why `[2.5]` after?

Comment: Yes It works, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is

```
print(recallFunc.item()(2.5))
```

or better way,

```
recallFunc=data['interpFunc'].item()
print(recallFunc(2.5))
```

Thanks [hpaulj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/901925/hpaulj)